# Can I use a "universal" flush valve (or different brand) in my Kohler toilet?

Tags: toilet

My toilet is leaking. I hear the leaking noise and sometimes I can even hear the filling valve being triggered when the level of water in the cistern becomes too low.

After investigating a little bit and cleaning the cistern and flapper valve I decided that probably I better replace the whole flush valve than just the flapper valve.

My toilet is a Kohler, and maybe an old model. I checked online to buy another flush valve, but what I see on the Internet does not like the flush valve I have right now. When I asked in the hardware store about buying new pieces to replace the old ones I was told that for this model (Kohler) I better use the house parts. Still, I can find online other products that say "fits Kohler".

Should I replace my toilet parts with the more expensive Kohler ones or can I try other brands?

Comment: In my experience "universal" toilet parts just means "common". They are **not** universal. I would take the part in question to a hardware store and find one that looks the same.

Comment: Kohler tends to require special parts. Take your old part to the store and visually compare. Also look for the model number of the toilet, which is usually cast on the underside of the tank lid or the inside wall of the tank.

Comment: @paulmz, Thank you. I already went with a picture of them to the HW store first time I was asking about parts. I also had checked the info beneath the lid of the water tank and googled pieces by serial number. That's how I learned that I didn't have anything that looked like the original parts for that model. But yes, everyones seems to suggest that with Kohler is better not to try another brand's parts.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the configuration of the flush valve. If it's the type with a 3-4 inch plastic tube that when lifted allows water to flush than you need to use that specific valve type from Kohler. If not and the valve is mounted through a standard (3/4 inch +/-) opening to the supply line you should be able to swap in any valve with minor adjustments to the lift handle and flapper. Post a photo of the Kohler valve.